# When does SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong() throw a NoSuchAlgorithmException?

Tags: java

The method [`SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html) declares that it can throw a `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, however the doc says:

> Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support at least one strong SecureRandom implementation.

Under which circumstances can this exception then be thrown? Could this only happen if the property `securerandom.strongAlgorithms` is user-defined and does not list an algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

It appears this exception is indeed thrown if `securerandom.strongAlgorithms` is incorrectly configured. An unchecked exception might have been a better choice.

[`SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-22%2B4/src/java.base/share/classes/java/security/SecureRandom.java#L942-L981):

```java
if (property == null || property.isEmpty()) {
    throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException(
        "Null/empty securerandom.strongAlgorithms Security Property");
}

...

throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException(
    "No strong SecureRandom impls available: " + property);
```